# Convert date range to timestamp

Tags: php

`$time_range_from_user = '2014-03-28 17:00:00 to 2014-03-28 18:00:00';`

Is there any way I can convert $time_range_from_user and to timestamp and return start time and end time separately?

Comment: explode on "to", to give you two array elements, trim the spaces, and convert using DateTime

Comment: You've already asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436449/find-date-and-time-in-a-given-date-range) almost an hour ago. You didn't get any answers to that one because the question was **unclear**. If you want help, please actually state what you're trying to achieve (along with the expected results, the code that you've tried so far, error messages (if any)).

Comment: It does not make much sense to ask like *"is there any way"* on Stackoverflow because as it's about programming, there *always* is, even if it needs to extend the language itself to offer the functionality needed. Instead you need to outline what exactly your programming question is, what you've tried so far and with which part exactly you've got a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[explode()](http://www.php.net/explode)** to separate a string on a chosen delimiter into an array. In this case we will use the delimiter ' to ' to separate the strings.

```
$time_range_from_user = '2014-03-28 17:00:00 to 2014-03-28 18:00:00';

$ranges = explode(' to ', $time_range_from_user); //Split string on ' to '

$start_timestamp = strtotime($ranges[0]); //Take first result and turn it into a timestamp

$end_timestamp = strtotime($ranges[1]); //Take second result and turn it into a timestamp

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_timestamp) . ' ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end_timestamp); //Output both time stamps in Y-m-d H:i:s format.
```

The variables `$start_timestamp` and `$end_timestamp` contain the UNIX timestamps of the representations of  `2014-03-28 17:00:00` and `2014-03-28 18:00:00` respectively. At the end I `echo` the output formatted using `date()` to match your initial format.

Comment: just little addition to convert string to time stamp: 
'$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd/m/Y H:i', '10/10/2012 10:10', new DateTimeZone('Something'));'

'$timestamp = $datetime->getTimestamp();'

Comment: Please add note, code only answer are bad. That is not an good answer either. You forget to convert to timestamp

Comment: Thanks for the input. Updated for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

em... just split it by ' to ' string? `$parts = explode(' to ', $time_range_from_user);`