# C# to PHP code for some timestamp generation

Tags: c#, php, timestamp

I am not a C# programmer, but was given an API where part of their code requires generating of a Timestamp but example was given in C# so I am stuck as to how I can get the same results in PHP. Can someone here help to show me how this code would be in Php?

```
DateTime dtStart = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString());
TimeSpan toNow = dtNow.Subtract(dtStart);
string timeStamp = toNow.Ticks.ToString().Substring(0, timeStamp.Length - 7);
```

I am sort of able to get the first 2 line into PHP, but 3rd line onwards, I am lost.

Comment: If you don't understand the code then you should run it in a test application. Observe the changes and output so that you can handle it on your own next time. If you rely too much on the community then you would keep on relying on them on the future. Good luck.

Comment: The thing is I don't have a C# environment to test.

Comment: There are online compilers for c# such as https://dotnetfiddle.net/. Check out this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yUnx0Y). Knowing the behavior of the code by trying it out yourself will assure you that the information you get from the community is accurate. You can then use the result as reference when you convert it to PHP.

Comment: And you can do the same for PH. for testing purpuse i will recommend fixing the DateTime.Now value so the result will be the same in both case.

Comment: and the `DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString());` make no sense..It's either `DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Parse("2021/01/01");` or `DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;`. Either you want to parse something or you use Now. But Now , To string , then parse is 2 useless operation.

Comment: you might also switch to `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()`.

Comment: Actually, this is an example code from an integration document showing how to generate the timestamp which would be used in combination with an AppId to generate a Signing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
<?php
$date = new DateTime(); // OR new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
?>
```

Comment: just like that? The line 3 in my code have a subtract function between 2 datetime

Comment: Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436959/convert-date-range-to-timestamp

Comment: @Juan, this will give local time. It will not be consitent with the expected result from C# that is UTC.